# Run an R-script from command line and store results in subdirectory

Tags: r, ubuntu, terminal, storing-data

I want to run an R-script from the command line (on a Linux machine) and store the results in a subdirectory of the working directory. It looks like that:

```
./myscript.r [param 1] [param 2] [param 3]
```

Given 3 binomial parameters there are 4 conditions in total. I want to store  the results of each condition in a subdirectory of the working directory.

Is there an elegant way to do that or do I really need to copy my R-script to every subdirectory?

Comment: Can't you take care of that in the R script itself whether via `save`, `write.csv`, etc.? You can create new directories from R using the `system` command.

Comment: could you pass the parameters within the script and have it write to each directory? Something like a `for` loop for each parameter?

Comment: If your R program writes to stdout, just pipe the output to a file specified relative to the current directory.

Comment: You should include a minimal representative example of your program to provide more context for your problem.

Answer (score 2):

Purcell,try saving and running this script on your computer. Provide it a few different kinds and combinations of arguments.

```
#!/usr/bin/Rscript
args <- commandArgs(TRUE)
print(args)
class(args)
```

For instance, I ran `./test.R test=1 one=test`.

Using this command in combination with `paste0()` statements should give you what you need to tailor your output locations based on the parameters provided.